# gsub() an entire column over another column

Tags: regex, r, dplyr

I have a df:

```
df <- data.frame(
    x=c("ABC Inc", "DCV", "FGZ", "JH7 j11"),
    y=c("ABC - fasjdlkjs", "DCV . (INC) .. kdhkfhksf", "FGZ / qiuwy72gs", "JH7 j11 dhd"),
    target=c("fasjdlkjs", "inc kdhkfhksf", "qiuwy gs", "dhd")
)
```

Where `x` is a close, but not exact subset of `y`

I want to gsub() everything in `x` to `""` (blank) in `y`, while also removing numbers/punctuation.

My desired output is stored in `target`

I thought this would have worked, but it didn't:

```
df <- mutate(target = gsub(pattern=x, replacement="", y))
```

EDIT:

Sort of: `Y - X = Target`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This (now - thanks @Frank) converts case `tolower`.  Below, `s` builds the string to test against from the `x` column by splitting the `x` string by spaces

```
df$res <- mapply(function(a, b) {
    s <- paste(c(unlist(strsplit(as.character(a)," ")), "[[:punct:]]"), collapse="|")
    tolower(gsub("[[:digit:]]+", " ", gsub(s, "", b)))
  }, df$x, df$y)

df
#         x                        y        target              res
# 1 ABC Inc          ABC - fasjdlkjs     fasjdlkjs        fasjdlkjs
# 2     DCV DCV . (INC) .. kdhkfhksf inc kdhkfhksf   inc  kdhkfhksf
# 3     FGZ          FGZ / qiuwy72gs      qiuwy gs         qiuwy gs
# 4 JH7 j11              JH7 j11 dhd           dhd              dhd
```

Comment: Sweet! ABC and INC are still left though. I'd like those gsub'ed out.

Comment: Oh I see, so it should remove any words that are in `x`, ie. not matching the whole string, but parts of it?